# Ignore Certificate Error in a Web Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

Is there a way of ignoring SSL certificate errors?

I have developed a web service which until now has been running locally using http, however it has been moved externally and needs to communicate via https. The certificate for testing purposes is self-signed and therefore not trusted and I am getting the error `The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.`

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="RemoteSoap" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://mydomainwebservice:8444/Test.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="RemoteSoap" contract="RemoteService.RemoteSoap"
    name="RemoteSoap" />
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If I add the following security element I then get the following error `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` which seems to be caused by `The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>
```

Can someone kindly advise as to ignore these errors?

Answer (score 4):

Try editing the config values in the .config

```
<configuration>
 <system.net>
  <settings>
    <servicePointManager
      checkCertificateName="false"
      checkCertificateRevocationList="false"      
    />
  </settings>
 </system.net>
</configuration>
```